# How to get higher res image from Google Books Api?

Tags: swift, google-books, google-books-api

When I try to get a higher resolution image from the google books API it only gives me the small thumbnail size that is 128 X 209 and I can't get a larger image

This is my url:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=colleen+hoover")
```

My Structs:

```
    struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}

struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    let title, publishedDate: String?
    let authors: [String]?
    let publisher, description: String?
    let imageLinks: ImageLinks?
    let averageRating: Double?
    
}

struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    let kind: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let items: [Book]
}

struct ImageLinks: Codable {
    let smallThumbnail, thumbnail: String
}
```

and this is how I'm downloading the image from the url

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                self?.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to fix this but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Instead of getting the image URL from the struct and using the thumbnail, I used this URL instead and just change the bookImgId variable to your book id

```
https://books.google.com/books/publisher/content/images/frontcover/\(bookImgId)?fife=w400-h600&source=gbs_api
```

This part of the URL is where you will change the image size to whatever you want

```
?fife=w400-h600
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time replacing `zoom=1` by `zoom=10` in the response coming from `volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail` would do the trick, but it doesn't work always. Sometimes you get that "image not found" image from Google, like [this one](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=0_1qQgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=10&source=gbs_api).

And when this happens there's no way around it since it probably means Google itself doesn't have a larger file to show.

I solved this with something that is a little overkill, but it works 100% of the time:

1. I used Vision library to detect the text inside the image
2. If the image has the words "`image not found`" I just replace it by my own default image.

I don't think Google will replace this 404 image anytime soon, but if it does I would need to adapt my code.

This is an example of text detection on images:

```
private func performOCR(on imageURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ([String]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let image = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL) else {
        completionHandler(nil, NSError(domain: "OCR", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to load image from URL."]))
        return
    }
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, options: [:])
    
    // Create a text recognition request
    let textRecognitionRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation],
              !observations.isEmpty else {
            completionHandler(nil, NSError(domain: "OCR", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No text found in the image."]))
            return
        }
        
        var detectedText: [String] = []
        for observation in observations {
            guard let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { continue }
            detectedText.append(topCandidate.string)
        }
        
        completionHandler(detectedText, nil)
    }
    
    textRecognitionRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    textRecognitionRequest.usesLanguageCorrection = true
    
    do {
        try handler.perform([textRecognitionRequest])
    } catch {
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}
```

And you can use this function like this:

```
private func googleImageNotFound(url: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // These are the words that appears on Google's default "image not found" image
    let keywords = ["image", "not", "found"]
    
    guard let imageUrl = URL(string: url) else {
        completion(true)
        return
    }
    
    performOCR(on: imageUrl) { detectedTexts, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("OCR Error: \(error)")
            completion(true) // Return true if there's an error
        } else if let detectedTexts = detectedTexts {
            let containsWords = detectedTexts.contains { detectedText in
                keywords.allSatisfy { word in
                    detectedText.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(word)
                }
            }
            completion(!containsWords) // Return true if words are not found
        } else {
            completion(true) // Return true if detectedTexts is nil
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import Vision:

```
import Vision
```